# How to refactor old Apple SDK files displaying build warnings in C++ with OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32()?

Tags: c++

I've got some build warnings using some older Apple SDK files, which I'm attempting to refactor to silence the warnings.
I'm confused by the syntax, and hoped someone might be able to help explain it.

An example call is
`OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32(mWriteIndex, (mWriteIndex + 1) & mMask, &mWriteIndex);`
Could you please help to explain `(mWriteIndex + 1) & mMask` ?

All arguments are defined as `int32_t` types.

I've tried to use std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit as described by the error message, but am getting No matching function for call using

```
std::atomic<int32_t> mReadIndex, mWriteIndex, mFreeIndex;

std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&mWriteIndex, (mWriteIndex + 1) & mMask, &mWriteIndex, std::memory_order_relaxed, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

'OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.12 - Use std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(std::memory_order_relaxed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding:

```
(mWriteIndex + 1) & mMask
```

`mWriteIndex + 1` is, of course, adding one to `mWriteIndex`.

Assuming `mMask` is an integer with only some number of the least-significant-bits set, then the `& mMask` part is an old trick to compute a modulo of `(mWriteIndex + 1)` without having to actually do a division/modulo operation -- e.g. if you wanted to compute `x % 16`, then `x & 0x0F` will give you the same result while potentially using fewer CPU cycles, as a bitwise-AND is traditionally faster than a divmod operation.  That trick only works for doing a modulo of a power-of-two, of course.

The code you present is most likely implementing a lock-free circular FIFO queue; in this scheme the size of the circular array will always be set to a power-of-two, specifically to allow this trick to work.

Regarding the upgrading of the `OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32()` function call to its modern/standard-C++ replacement, I think you want something like this:

```
int32_t expectedVal = mWriteIndex.load();
mWriteIndex.compare_exchange_strong(expectedVal, (mWriteIndex + 1) & mMask, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the modulo trick there Jeremy, I had not seen that syntax before so it scrambled my brain a bit alongside all these errors I'm trying to squash. I managed to get a fix for the `compare_exchange_strong` call with ```return ((std::atomic<int64_t>)*__theValue).compare_exchange_weak(__oldValue, __newValue, std::memory_order_relaxed, std::memory_order_relaxed);```